# Работа в фоновом режиме

Tags: android

Запускаю приложение. Работает. Сворачиваю или открываю поверх другое приложение и моё приложение перестаёт работать (идёт постоянный обмен по сети). Как заставить работать приложение в фоновом режиме?

Answer (score 4):

Для начала надо изучить жизненный цикл компонентов приложения.

Если вы осуществляете сетевой обмен в Activity, то это не правильно. Как только Вы скрываете Activity, или открываете другое приложение, оно (Activity) "замирает". Чтобы сетевой обмен проходил в фоне, его надо осуществлять в сервисе. Соответственно изучайте как работать с сервисами.

Вот [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/165-urok-100-service-intentservice-foreground-avtozagruzka-servisa.html) есть хороший урок на тему сервиса и на тему Foreground

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать через  [Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html)