# Android Отправка запросов в фоне

Tags: java, android

Нужно отправлять post запрос на сервер, дабы проверить, есть ли уведомления для этого приложения. Как это реализовать, понятия не имею. Использовал один сервис PushBots, с него не идут уведомления на телефоны типа Meizu. Суть такая, пользователь закрыл приложение, занимается своими делами, а фоновые задачи приложения в фоне отправляют запрос каждые 30 секунд и если есть уведомления, уведомляют пользователя

```
Intent intent= new Intent(this, NotificationListener.getClass()); startService(intent);
```

Так в MainActivity я объявляю свой сервис

```
public class NotificationListener extends Service {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public NotificationListener() {
    }

    public static final int JOB_ID = 0x01;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Post post = (Post) new Post().execute("тут url", "user_id=" + sharedPreferences.getInt("userId",0));
                try {
                    ShowNotification(post.get());
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    Log.i("MSG","SOMETHING ERROR " + e);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.i("MSG","SOMETHING ERROR " + e);
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        }, 0);
        return START_STICKY;
    }



    private void ShowNotification(String result) {

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            if (dataJsonObj.has("notification")) {
                JSONArray getNotify = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("notification");
                String content = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < getNotify.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject notify = getNotify.getJSONObject(i);
                    content += notify.getString("content");

                }
                Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

                notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

                //builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                builder.setContentTitle("У вас новый заказ!");
                NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
                bigTextStyle.setBigContentTitle("У вас новый заказ!");
                bigTextStyle.bigText(content);
                builder.setContentText(content);
                builder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                Bitmap largeIconBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
                builder.setLargeIcon(largeIconBitmap);
                builder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);

                Notification notification = builder.build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager =
                        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                startForeground(1, notification);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

Android Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"></service>
```

Comment: Выделяете отдельный поток под эту задачу и в нем в фоне делаете свои POST отправки. Через любую библиотеку с которой вам будет удобно работать. Также зависит от того, в каком формате JSON/*XML или еще что-то, принимает сервер. Meizu тут не причем, мы же можете локально с компьютера протестировать приложение, через всякие эмуляторы

Comment: Формат JSON. Меня волнует именно тот вопрос, как запустить что-то работать в фоне, при выключенном приложении. 7 часов провел в гугле ничего не работает

Comment: Ну так правильно, если бы 7 часов писали и код и он бы не работал, то понятно, а так... просто читать и ничего не писать, конечно не будет работать ))) [Вот](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/services-theory.php) и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/435327/216510) вам для начала. А еще [вот](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). Давно на андроид не писал, но с виду, не сложно разобраться. В чем именно проблема? код в студию

Comment: Понимаешь в чем проблема, сервисы в том виде, что их предлагают в гугле, работают на реальном устройстве Meizu, но не работают на Le Eco. За эти 7 часов мой мозг уже не варит

Comment: Так поэтому и говорю, код показывай, говори где ошибка или где блокировка происходит. В противном случае, берешь wireshark смотришь где пакеты теряются, если в дебаггере вообще не видно, что может вернуться.

Comment: В посте добавил код

Comment: Хорошо, много кода. А теперь, что значит "не идут уведомления" ? На какой строчке они ломаются или куда они недоходят или в каком формате?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы они в фоне работали, при закрытии приложения. Они работают, пока приложение работает. Как только ты закрываешь его, 2 секунды и процесс умирает. Но опять же, на Meizu он не умирает а дальше работает

Comment: Вообщем, мне надо как-то побороться с тем, что телефон убивает этот сервис. В целом все работает, если бы он не убивал. Android 6.0.1

Comment: А по чему бы вам не изучить FireBase или что-то подобное, зачем изобретать костыли их и так уже полные штаны! Почему вы решили что сервиса что вы написали не идут на Meizu? Может вы что-то не правильно делаете? Ведь с пушами большая проблема у самсугов, они любят тушить всё что не ихнее, и решалось это только в выполнении пользователем определённых действий из 6-7 пунктов. Но решение найдено, погуглите внимательно на тему пуши и энергосберегающий режим. https://www.aqua-mail.com/forum/index.php?topic=2684.0 https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/solve-android-delayed-notifications/

Comment: Как через FireBase отправлять сообщение определенному пользователю?

Comment: FireBase работает на гугл сервисах, в оболочке Flyme эти сервисы не предустановлены. Можно конечно сказать человеку, чтобы установил. Но тот же ВК, инстраграмм и т.п как то обходят эту систему